# Alamofire - "no such module" error

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm getting a "no such module" error when integrating Alamofire via CocoaPods. Even when I create a new empty project and simply add the Alamofire dependency.

```
pod --version
0.38.2

xcodebuild -version
Xcode 6.3.2
Build version 6D2105
```

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0.0-beta.3'
```

I hope someone can help me with this. Please tell me if you need further information!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem was the Xcode version**

For anybody who has a similar problem: I just updated to Xcode 7.0.1 and everything works now, yay!

Answer (score -1):

Import almofire in the file you needed

Comment: Yeah I do that, actually that's the line where the error is shown ;) I think my problem is the Xcode version, just read the requirement "Xcode 7.0+". But for some reason I can't click the install button in the App Store.

Answer (score -1):

import Alamofire after importing UIKit
Then comment it out, build the project.
Uncomment it.

For some reason building the project first without Alamofire then importing it 'just works'. I had the same bug (had installed Alamofire from Cocoapods, checked it was target 9.0, podfile included Alamofire, library binary was linked etc, updated Xcode to 7.3 and still no success). This solved it.